# Disable autogenerated parameter hint in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I tried to find the relevant setting to disable this feature but coudln't find any. Basically whenever I press Enter (using python) to accept a suggestion, vscode adds that parameter hint which is pretty annoying specially if you also have vim extension installed. Any idea how to disable it?

Already tried `"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false,` which didn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default [Python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) extension doesn't have this kind of issue (using Pylance).
I only have these 2 settings enabled :

```
"python.analysis.completeFunctionParens": true,
"python.analysis.typeCheckingMode": "strict"
```

The first autocompletes the brackets (without the parameters) and the second enables type checking.

I tested with the [Vim](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim) extension and can't reproduce either.

Here's what I got:
[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqo3H.gif)

I would be happy to help you more if you could provide what extensions you are using.

Comment: So for some reason Pylance was disabled for me. I enabled it and added the following lines in my setting file and things seem to work fine now: ` "python.languageServer": "Pylance"` and `"python.analysis.completeFunctionParens": true`